# Performing AND on mongo multikey compound query (with or without mongoid)

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

I have a data structure of the following format:

```
{
  topAttribute: {
      subAttribute:
         [
          { eventType: "SPECIAL", date: "20121231" }
          { eventType: "NOTSPECIAL", date: "20131012" }
          { eventType: "NOTSPECIAL", date: "20131122" }
          ...
         ]
      }
 }
```

I'm trying to identify records which have an eventType of 'SPECIAL' AND a date of '20121231". I'm trying to accomplish this with the following multikey-style query:

Mongoid:

```
Item.where('topAttribute.subAttribute.eventType' => 'SPECIAL').and('topAttribute.subAttribute.date' => '20121231').all
```

MongoDB:

```
db.items.find( { 'topAttribute.subAttribute.eventType': 'SPECIAL', 'topAttribute.subAttribute.date': '20121231'} )
```

However, when I run this query, it finds *either* records with eventType of 'SPECIAL' *OR* records with date of '20121231'. This is not the result I want.

How could I restructure this query -- or use another search/aggregation strategy -- to only show records with with eventType of 'SPECIAL' *AND* records with date of '20121231', and exclude all others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to find documents with array elements which satisfy all of your fields, you need to use the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator.

```
db.items.find( 
    { 'topAttribute.subAttribute' : {
        $elemMatch: {
             'eventType': 'SPECIAL',
             'date': '20121231'
        }
    } 
);
```